# Redefinition of variable name with a different type

Tags: objective-c, variables, compiler-errors, scope

I am trying to send a push notification to my app.Here, through the code below I am trying to get the device token but I get a compiler error:

> Redifinition of 'deviceToken' with a different type: 'NSString*__strong' vs 'NSData*__strong'

Here is my code.

```
    NSString *deviceToken = [[[[deviceToken description]
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""] 
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
```

Comment: You can't have two variables with the same name in the same scope. Rename one of them.

Comment: replaced the deviceToken with devToken.. still same error..

Comment: Show more code. Show your `NSData` version of `deviceToken`.

Comment: you want to get device token or want to send push notification ?

Comment: actually i got this code from this site http://iosapplove.com/archive/2012/10/apns-tutorial-how-to-send-pushnotifications-to-my-app/#more-77

Comment: @sanjeet i want to get the device token but without "<", ">" or spaces to store it into my database

Comment: edit your question and explain clearly.

Comment: We don't care where you got the code. Post *your* code in your question.

Comment: @rmaddy i dont have the NSdata version for deviceToken.. this is all the code i have for deviceToken

Comment: You must have another `deviceToken` declared somewhere since you are calling the `description` method on it.

Comment: yes sorry my bad.. i found a solution to it. thanks @rmaddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this code you can get deviceToken

```
NSString *deviceTokenId = [[[deviceToken description]
                  stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]]
                 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                 withString:@""];
```

Comment: yes the code that i used above was the old way of doing it and was no longer supported by xcode5... thank you sanjeet for you answer.